# <hr> not changing height in head css

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the height of the hr tag but it only works if I put the code inline. If I put it within style in the head it doesn't work. Everything else does, colour, length, but the height will not.
What am I doing wrong?
`hr {height: 10px;}`
Thanks for your help

Comment: Please red [ask] and update your question with a [mcve]

Comment: Perhaps the height is being inherited by another CSS rule found in another CSS file? Maybe, there's another CSS rule somewhere that affects (overides) the style in the head? Can you provide the full code?

Comment: i cannot reproduce your issue. please see my jsfiddle and advise https://jsfiddle.net/7mpov06e/2/

Comment: So I found the issue and yes it's css from another file. It's in reboot.css from the cdn that I'm using.
Thanks all for your input.